# How to destroy a body with CCPhysicsSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics, box2d-iphone

I've realized that CCPhysicsSprite is different in a few ways from CCSprite. For example, you must set the body before you set the position of the sprite. I believe it is one of these differences that is causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I try destroying the body. I call the scheduleSprite method in the update method.

```
-(void)scheduleSprite {

if ([testSprite physicsSprite].b2Body != NULL) {
b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(-5, 10.0 * [testSprite physicsSprite].b2Body->GetMass());
[testSprite physicsSprite].b2Body->ApplyForce(force, [testSprite physicsSprite].b2Body->GetWorldCenter() );

if ([testSprite physicsSprite].position.x < 0) {
world->DestroyBody([testSprite physicsSprite].b2Body);
[testSprite physicsSprite].b2Body = NULL;
    }
}
}
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS pointing to line

```
b2Vec2 pos  = _b2Body->GetPosition();
```

in the

```
-(CGAffineTransform) nodeToParentTransform
```

method, within the class

```
CCPhysicsSprite.mm
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS error and strange behaviour when moving box2d body in straight horizontal line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055026/exc-bad-access-error-and-strange-behaviour-when-moving-box2d-body-in-straight-ho)

Answer (score 1):

Despite you destroyed the `body`, the `sprite` will keep doing its stuff, so you may remove the sprite from its parent also, something like.-

```
if ([testSprite physicsSprite].position.x < 0) {
    world->DestroyBody([testSprite physicsSprite].b2Body);
    [[testSprite physicsSprite] removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```

Comment: I've just added the above code but I still get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Only this time it is pointing to the line `if ([testSprite physicsSprite].b2Body != NULL) { `  in the `scheduleSprite ` method.

Comment: Mmh what about setting the body reference to `null`, as you were doing before? (just between `destroy` and `removeFromParent` calls)

Comment: Ok, didn't realized before, but maybe is `[testSprite physicsSprite]` what is throwing the exception, so you may try also `testSprite.physicsSprite = NULL;`

Comment: ... and in your if statements, you may check also for [testSprite physicsSprite] != nil

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) killBody:(cpBody*)body
{
    cpBodyEachShape_b(body, ^(cpShape *shape) {
        cpSpaceRemoveShape( _space, shape );
        cpShapeFree(shape);
    });
    cpSpaceRemoveBody( _space, body );
    cpBodyFree(body);//edited to include this line

    CCPhysicsSprite*    sprite = (__bridge CCPhysicsSprite*) body->data;
    [sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:true];
}
```

I was getting the same thing, the method above seemed to fix it. 
First, remove the shapes attached to the body from the space. I'm using _space as a instance variable pointing to a cpSpace object. Next, remove the body from the space. Finally, remove the sprite from the parent.

When I make a CCPhysicsSprite object, I connect its body to the sprite using body->data. You can see that in the method above.

If you are starting with a CCPhysicsSprite object, you would first get the cpBody object from the sprite, then remove the body and shape as shown above.